# Azure App Configuration: Double underscore not equivalent to colon when trying to denote nesting

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-app-configuration

In Azure App Configuration I have named my settings as so: "Section1__SubSection1__MySetting".  When trying to bind configuration to my corresponding Options class in my .NET 6 application, it fails to map correctly (null).  If I change the "__" to ":" it works fine.

I'm trying to untangle why/how you can use double underscore to denote nesting, because it is generally recommended to use "__" for more universal support.  If I use ":" in my Azure App Configuration keys, would it still work if I run my app on a Linux machine?

Can someone please explain all this?

Comment: AFAIK, `:` will not work in Linux Environment.

Comment: Can share your App Settings Screencap.

Comment: And also share the code which you are trying to bind the Configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Written with [StackEdit](>Double underscore not equivalent to colon when trying to denote nesting

Yes, denoting nested configuration varies depending on the Hosting Environment (Windows/Linux).

If you want to set the nested configuration in Windows App, then you need to mention the `:` symbol following the nested key name (which you have already tried).

You can see that same is mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings)

> In a default Linux app service or a custom Linux container, any nested JSON key structure in the app setting name like `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey` needs to be configured in App Service as `ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey` for the key name. In other words, any `:` should be replaced by `__` (double underscore).

- From the above document it is clear that to bind nested configuration in Linux Environment, we need to use `__`  double underscore.

***Check the below workaround:***

- I have followed the [Azure App Configuration with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x)  to add the Nested Configuration.
- I have created a Web App and deployed to `Linux App Service`.
- Initially I have set the Configuration with `:`  and `__`

[image]

and tried to retrieve the values.

***In `Program.cs`:***

```cs
string myconn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
//string myconn = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig").Value;
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(myconn);
```

***In `Index.cshtml`:***

```cs
<h4>With Semicolon - @myconfig["Test:Settings:SemiColon"]</h4>
<h4>With UnderScore - @myconfig["Test__Settings__UnderScore"]</h4>
```

***Local Output:***

[image]

I have deployed the App to `Azure Linux App service`.

***Deployed App Output:***

[image]

Both  `:`  and `__` worked for me for the deployed app in `Linux App Environment` with `Azure App Configuration`.

***When I tried same with `Azure App Settings`,***

***Local `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
"Section1": {
  "SubSection1": {
    "MySetting": "Value from Local"
  }
}
```

- Initially I have set the Configuration with `:` and tried to retrieve the value.

***Local Output:***
[image]

- `:`  worked here.
- I have deployed the App to `Azure Linux App service`.
- To override the value with the Azure App Settings, I have set the value as below (with`:`).

[image]

- You can see the below error while adding the setting.

[image]

- I have tried with `__` and it allowed me to add.

[image]

***Deployed App Output:***

[image]

> If I use ":" in my Azure App Configuration keys, would it still work if I run my app on a Linux machine?

- Yes, `:`  works on `Azure Linux App Service` in `Azure App Configuration`.
- Whereas only `__` worked on `Azure Linux` with `Azure App Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It helped explain a lot.  So it seems Azure App Configuration provider is automatically handling the conversion of ":" to "__" in Linux environments if I am understanding correctly, right?

Comment: @killswitch - Not the conversion.We cannot edit the key name,only the value can be changed.App Configuration is accepting `__` new entry.

Comment: But since ":" works on Azure Linux App Service, then it must be that the provider is interpreting it as "__" for it to work?

Comment: Yes..as per the workaround I observed that both are working.